# Forcing javascript file to refresh in IE 11

Tags: c#, javascript, bing-maps, webmatrix, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a problem with IE11.  It keeps displaying the data it gained from a javascript routine the first time the js file was run.

Changing the search parameters on the page should re-run the js file but its not in IE11.

The problem doesn't occur in Firefox 26. Also, I can stop it by manually in IE11 by changing my IE options for "check for newer versions of stored pages" to 'check everytime I visit'.
While this is fine for me its not a reasonable solution for users.

Appending a random number to the javascript file reference doesn't have any impact.

How can I easily make the javascript file re-load ever time its called?

Other environmentals include: webmatrix c#, json, bing maps

Comment: Do you host this JavaScript file? Have you tried setting the expires and cache-control max-age headers?

Comment: [geek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20933145/413180) should work - what HTTP response code do you see for the `.js` with random number appended, and is the URL requested correctly?

Comment: As has been stated clearly, appending a unique query string **is** the correct way to get a fresh response. That being said, you should check the network traffic, and the headers for this request/response, for additional information. Please share that information here. Also, make sure the query string is unique for **every request**.

Comment: @MudMaps Have you managed to resolve your problem? Or is this still an issue for you? Are you able to answer some of our questions so we can assist you?

Answer (score 1):

add some variable parameter at end of js file

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
<script src="/my/js/javascriptfile.js?<?=somrandomnumber()?>"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: From the OP `Appending a random number to the javascript file reference doesn't have any impact.`

Comment: @geek Internet Explorer 10+ doesn't support conditional comments. The user is using C#, not PHP.